# SQL and Notifications

Tags: android, sql, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

Currently I'm setting up an alarm which when activated displays a notification to the user.

I can now set the text from my SQL to my notification but its only the first row from my database each time. Now I've come up with two possible solutions which are only theory's.

Is there a way in which each time the database is called to the notification it will move onto the next result?

As I mentioned above I'm setting an alarm and when the alarm goes off it then calls the notification. Now In my pending intent for the alarm I'm giving it a id which you can see as id is there a way of giving it to my notification ID and then setting up a statement where if the notification ID is equal to or in the list of my alarm ID's stored on my SQL then it will search for the correct text to input.

Pending Intent....

```
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), id,  receiver,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

 intentArrayList.add(pendingIntent);
```

Broadcast....

```
MyDatabaseHandler myDatabaseHandler = new MyDatabaseHandler(context, null, null, 1);

Cursor cursor = myDatabaseHandler.getAllProducts();


// Information we are trying to acquire but can only get first result
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("alarm_name"));
String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("alarm_date"));

// Alarm ID FROM SQL which we want to match with the NOTIFICATION ID.....
String alarm_request_code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("alarm_code"));



 ////




 Log.i("The reciever is working", "perfect");

//create an intent to service

Intent service_Intent = new Intent(context, MessageService.class);
context.startService(service_Intent);

//Notification

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManagercontext.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



Intent moveActivity = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);


moveActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

// Works with moveActivity to move the user back to main application.
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,moveActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setContentTitle(name)
    .setContentText(date)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setAutoCancel(true);




    notificationManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(alarm_request_code), builder.build());



}
}
```

////////////////////////////////////

Clearing up some issues

1. Whenever my alarm goes off currently a notification is sent to the user with a static name and description.
2. What I'm trying to accomplish is that when this alarm goes off, my notification is either given an ID matching the one of Alarm or looks up the alarm to then populate the text and title of the notification with the active alarms details.
3. This is what my current layout looks like inside of my SQLiteOpenHelper

   ```
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarmList.db";
   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "alarm_list";

   public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
   public static final String COLUMN_ALARMTIME = "alarm_time";
   public static final String COLUMN_AlARMDATE = "alarm_date";
   public static final String COLUMN_ALARMNAME = "alarm_name";


   // Alarm request code column for working with switch and
   public static final String COLUMN_ALARMRC = "alarm_code";
   ```

Followed by default oncreate and update methods

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a few different ways. One would be to add a `last_used` date column, or a `use_count` column, and update that each time the record is used. You would then have a query that selects the least used item from your table.

Another way would be to store your alerts within your application and track that information there. The downside of that would be that, unless you store that count/last-used information out (probably to an external stats file) you would lose those counts when you restarted the application.

The concept would really be the same any way you were to approach this. You need to store usage information about your alerts somewhere.

I think this is what you are asking for, but after re-reading your question a few times, I am not as certain. Maybe you could provide some samples of your table structure and some of the data from those tables, and also provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish. If what I have here in my answer isn't what you are looking for, no worries. I will either update it to be more in-line with what you need or remove it altogether. Just want to make sure it is what you are looking for.

More on the `last_used` query, as requested:

You would want to write a query similar to:

```
select alert_id, alert_group, alert_text
from alerts
where alert_group = @parm_alert_group
order by last_used asc
limit 1 -- this may be different depending on the flavor of DBMS used
-- Oracle does not have "limit", but can be reproduced in other ways.
;
```

Then, when you use that alert item, you would want to update that record with the current datetime so that the next time your select query returns the record used longest ago.

```
update alerts set last_used = now() where alert_id = @parm_alert_id;
```

You could of course perform both of those actions within a function that returns the alert information and updates the `last_used` column before returning it, but that is just bonus functionality. The same idea is there using two separate calls, or a single call.

Comment: Hi I know exactly what you mean, I've been trying to sort this out for the last couple of hours. currently when I set an alarm I've told my application to store an ID which is related to that alarm. Would you be able to expand on your last used query and how I would implement it? Also thank you for your time.

Comment: @Steven - Added some more info for you.

Comment: I think we are on the right tracks I've updated a section above to try and clarify the issue.